# React Native Bottom Tab bar like on Instagram

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have searched a lot about Navigation in React Native. I saw a lot of possibilities but I never found something like on Instagram. I **did** found a Bottom Tab bar Navigation, but there is always:

a) An animation

b) A Text

c) A color

d) .........

But I never found a bar like this. **Do I have to use React Navigation for Nativgation** or is it just helpful? What if I don't use it? :) And how could I do a menu bar like this *(I think you all know how Instagram Navigation works)*:

[image: Bottom Tab Bar]

Btw. I don't use expo :)

Comment: You can set custom icons, animations, and colors in the react nav libraries. Are you asking about making your own? It's probably not recommended

Comment: @JonahG I mean not only the bar - I do have this - I mean the full navigation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';`  because I was having many problems with the `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs`.

To use on bottom you can do this:

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();


        ...


  <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Home"
            tabBarPosition="bottom"
            lazy={true}
            tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: colors.orange,
                inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
                showIcon: true,
                indicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
                labelStyle: {
                    fontFamily: 'GothamRounded-Bold',
                    fontSize: widthPercentageToDP('3%'),
                    bottom: 1.5,
                    alignSelf: 'flex-start'
                },
                activeTintColor: colors.orange,
                inactiveTintColor: colors.greyLight,
                style: {
                    elevation: 5,
                    shadowColor: '#000',
                    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
                    shadowOffset: {
                        height: 1,
                        width: 0
                    },
                    position: 'absolute',
                    width: widthPercentageToDP('100%'),
                    zIndex: 8,
                    borderTopColor: 'transparent',
                    bottom: keyboard,
                    justifyContent: 'center'
                },
                upperCaseLabel: false
            }}>

              ...
```

And then you can customize as you want

To change icon I do this:

```
   <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={Home}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                        <FastImage
                            source={focused ? homeOrange : homeGrey}
                            style={{ flex: 1, width: null, height: null }}
                            resizeMode="contain"
                        />
                    ),
                    tabBarLabel: 'Home'
                }}
            />
```

Comment: Hey. That is nice, thank you. What are the problems with react navigation tab bottom? :)

Comment: Using bottom tab you have few options to handle by props, which limits you to several things like swipe with your finger to change screen (only pressing the tab bar is possible) and styling is also a little more complicated

Comment: Uh, okay! Nice to know. That I will take a look to your code :D